# search user in uiwebview as a logged in user in facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating app with facebook. I am getting user info and publish_stream permission. After user logs in user can search other user directly from `UIWebView`. I was able to do so when there is accessToken. Using this i was showing other user's profile as current user.

`storing in variable when user logs in for future purpose.`

```
url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://facebook.com/search/results.php?q=SEARCH_USER&type=user&access_token=%@",self.selectedMatch.realName,facebookAccessToken];
```

But, now as access token is deprecated there is `accessTokenData`. 
But I am not able to show it as a current user, it directly takes user to facebook login page. Any one knows how i can do this using the latest SDK of facebook ?

I tried with this but it display facebook login screen.

```
url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://facebook.com/search/results.php?q=NAME&type=user&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"];
```

Comment: Why not just use accessTokenData.accessToken?

Comment: see my edited question. Its still doesn't working. am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done by specifying web view as default behavior like this.

```
[[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:
    ^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state,NSError *error)
    {
        if(state == FBSessionStateOpen)
       {
        // code when login is successful.
       }
    }];
```

If you are using webview for user to login then you can display any specific as logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

accessTokenData is of type FBAccessTokenData and has a property accessToken which is a NSString. Just use this as you used the access token before and it should work I guess:

```
url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://facebook.com/search/results.php?q=NAME&type=user&access_token=%@", accessTokenData.accessToken];
```

Here's some more info on that topic: [Facebook: Making API Calls to Publish with an App Access Token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/)

Comment: I don't think Facebook's web interface supports passing an API access token to bypass or replace the website login - where did you see that?

Comment: Well BSThakrar mentioned that in his question and that it worked with an older version of the FB SDK. It sounded like he just got trouble getting the access token in the new SDK. I added a link to my answer

Comment: before i was using fbgraph library, in tht it's working. In tht when ever i open any url and pass access token , it opens as logged in user. But by using Facebook SDK, its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to log into facebook now to request private information regarding an account, this was changed so that your apps can't get user information with out permission from the user. So you have a main user

```
[FBSession activeSession]
```

and with that main user you ask for information. Such as their friends list:

```
 FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];

 [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary* result, NSError *error) {

 }];
```

this code defaults to using the token data which is associated with the session object aka in this example

```
[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData]
```

for using the graph api to access any random person's facebook to see the public data you can do this by the below code using Mark Zuckerberg's facebook the founder of facebook as the example
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mark-Zuckerberg/112845672063384

```
FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
FBRequest *request = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                                      graphPath:@"112845672063384"];
[newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
   NSDictionary* facebookUserPublicInfo = (NSSDictionary*)result;
}];
[newConnection start]
```

I guess i've never actually had to use the access token data in methods, it was always assumed to be that of the activeSession, but if you did the access token data IS the access token they just renamed it and it might carry other meta data

Comment: But if user has already logged in our app then it should display as logged in user.And i guess this will fetch data in dictionary.I dont want that i want to display user profile page in uiwebview.

Comment: nd I dont want to see any friend's profile, user should be able to see any user's public profile.

Comment: take a UIWebView and give it this url https://www.facebook.com/fbid with the id of the individual you want

Comment: will tht open it as a logged in user, if user is logged in previously in my app?

Comment: it shouldn't since that is public data

Comment: bt if user has already logged in tht measn user has given access to use it. then why can't we use?

Comment: if the user is logged in and you are requesting some type of data that you need to be logged in to get, and you get the log ing screen, then you must be closing the session by accident or using a different session by accident, because the method skips over the log in ui if you are logged in

Comment: are you asking if the user is logged into facebook, then starts your app up and tries to do facebook things, but it ask the user ot log in when the device is already logged into a facebook account?

Comment: yes user is logged in my app previously. bt i dont know i can use current FBsession to search user in UIwebview. I tried with url specified in que.

Answer (score 1):

The way Facebook works has been changed. You have everything you need here : https://developers.facebook.com/ios/.

The part that you want is probably this one : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/show-friends/.

Comment: This can only be used for who are friends with me, not for all the users.